# Send data over TCP/IP with Netcat or Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, tcp, netcat

I have an IP of the server and a port on which I'm able to connect via nc on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
> nc x.x.x.x PORT
```

In order to communicate with the server, the first step is to send a WAKEUP call and get acknowledgment. The server expects a 3 byte ID in the wakeup call. An example is provided in the documentation that shows the success scenario of sending the ID and receiving the ack using a software. i.e

The client sends:

```
<sy><sy><eq>111<et>
```

And the server responds with:

```
<sy><ak>A<et><cr>
```

Here is some detail of `<sy>`

> Within <> brackets is a non-printable ASCII character (`<sy>` = ASCII 22 or Hex 0x16)

I tried to replicate the exact same scenario but failed to do so. The server doesn't respond to the data I send, although the data is received there. I'm not sure about these tags `<sy><sy><eq>` etc. How to send the ID(111) along with these tags `<sy>` correctly?

Also tried to send this data using Rails framework and [Bindata](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata) ruby gem but don't know how to represent the above format.

Answer (score 1):

`netcat` is probably the wrong tool for this. Or at least you will want to use some other program to feed it input.

If I were doing this, I would code up something in python or C that would both connect to the server and feed it whatever data I needed to send it (and receive/interpret the responses) leaving out `nc` altogether. There are many examples on the web.

You can encode the control characters in a byte string in python with the syntax `b'\x16'` for your `<sy>` character. Most other languages have an equivalent capability.

I can't be sure exactly what those  characters are. It seems likely they are standard ASCII control characters, but they aren't using the standard abbreviations (see http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ for example). So presumably the documentation you are looking at has a list of the corresponding values. Assuming for the sake of example that `<eq>` corresponds to the ASCII ENQ character and `<et>` to the ASCII EOT (and given you already know that `<sy>` is equivalent to ASCII SYN), your desired string `<sy><sy><eq>111<et>` can be encoded in a python byte string: `b'\x16\x16\x05111\x04'`

(or equivalently `b'\x16\x16\x05\x31\x31\x31\x04'` if you like regularity: the `1` characters are simply ASCII digits, so you can replace each `1` with its binary equivalent `b'\x31'`)

To return to `nc`, trying to type in the control characters to the `nc` input from a terminal window is, while possible in most cases, very difficult and error-prone. You will need to know the equivalent control character mapping (for example, 0x16 is "Ctrl-V") and will need to know how to get the terminal to accept that literal character (coincidentally, in linux, you have to precede most control characters with a Ctrl-V in order to enter them as input and avoid having them interpreted in the usual way: Ctrl-D == EOF, Ctrl-C == Interrupt, Ctrl-W == Delete-Previous-Word, etc).

So if you wanted to enter the data above into `nc`'s input from the command line, you would need to type these characters:

```
Ctrl-V Ctrl-V              <sy> / SYN
Ctrl-V Ctrl-V              <sy> / SYN
Ctrl-V Ctrl-E              <eq> / ENQ
1
1
1
Ctrl-V Ctrl-D              <et> / EOT
```

But also important to note is that ordinarily `nc` will not actually send anything until you enter a newline (i.e. press the Return key). Then that newline character will also get sent to the server which might not be what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this using Ruby on Rails framework and a gem called Bindata https://github.com/dmendel/bindata but not success yet.